# How could you test receiving streaming/chunked data in node.js?

Tags: javascript, http, node.js, streaming

I've been exploring the node.js api, and I ran across the "data" event for HTTP servers. My question is this: assuming a dead-simple app like below, how could I send data, and debug the stream?

```
var http = require("http");

http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    req.setEncoding("utf8");
    req.on("data", function(data){
        console.log("request:\n" + data);
    });
}).listen(3000, "127.0.0.1");
```

I've tried using telnet and curl to send requests, but I haven't had any success. Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

It seems I was confusing HTTP and TCP. If you write a TCP server, rather than an HTTP server:

```
var net = require("net");

net.createServer(function(req, res){
    req.on("data", function (data) {
        console.log("request:" + data);
    });
}).listen(3000, "127.0.0.1");
```

you can easily test/debug streaming data to the server via telnet (or netcat):

```
$ telnet 127.0.0.1 3000

Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.

> this text
> should get
> streamed to
> node.js TCP server
```